# C++: Best way to destruct static stuff

Tags: c++, static, destructor

When I have a class containing static stuff, how can I free the memory at the end of the application the best way?

**Foo.h**

```
class GLUtesselator;

class Foo
{
private:
    static GLUtesselator *tess;
public:
    Foo();
    virtual ~Foo();
}
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.h"

#include <GL/glu.h>

GLUtesselator *Foo::tess = gluNewTess(); // System call

Foo::Foo() {}
Foo::~Foo()
{
     // And of course I don't want to destruct it here,
     // because I'm going to use the tesselator in other instances of Foo
     // Otherwise:
     // gluDeleteTess(tess);
}
```

Are there better alternatives to making a method to remove static stuff and call it when the app terminates?
Or can I say: "Oh, whatever, the application is terminated. The OS will free the memory..." ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple. Don't make the static member a pointer.
Then it will be correctly constructed and destructed.

Foo.h

```
#include <GL/glu.h>

class Foo
{
    private:
        static GLUtesselator  tess;
    public:
                 Foo();
        virtual ~Foo();
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
// 
GLUtesselator  Foo::tess;
```

If you have to use the gluNewTess() and gluDeleteTess() then you can use a shared pointer. I don't have a compiler so the exact usage may not be absolutely correct. But the shared_ptr does have this ability.

Foo.h

```
#include <GL/glu.h>

typedef std::shared_ptr<GLUtesselator,void (*)(GLUtesselator*)> AutoGluTess;
class Foo
{
    private:
        static AutoGluTess  tess;
    public:
                 Foo();
        virtual ~Foo();
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
// 
AutoGluTess    Foo::tess(gluNewTess(), &gluDeleteTess);
```

Comment: I think the code above does exactly what you want. The only possible downside is the extra header dependencies.

Comment: Indeed! Sorry, I didn't see the static keyword!

Comment: using shared_pointer it's possible NOT to include GL/glu.h, also the deleter can be supplied in the .cpp file and does not impact the shared_ptr type (at least... with boost implementation, it would be a regression if the std version suffered from this flow).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to destroy it. All operating systems I know will correctly free the memory and release any resources held by the object on application termination (Note: the destructor will not be called automatically, but the resources will be freed).

If you *really* want to destroy it though, either

1. Don't use a pointer as Martin York describes,
2. Or (if you need a pointer), use an `auto_ptr` or `tr1::unique_ptr` so that the pointee is automatically deleted when it goes out of scope (which is at the end of the application for static variables).

Comment: I really think this is terrible advice. Not every resource is freed, and it's awful practice to get in to. "Leaks? Who gives a..." Fix the code!

Comment: I agree, which is why I described how to destroy it properly. Please don't exaggerate by extrapolating my advice to ignoring memory leaks.

Comment: "You don't need to destroy it." and "If you *really* want to destroy it though" doesn't sound like "you should fix the code/leaking is bad" to me.

Comment: I'm trying -- and failing -- to see what kind of leak you could possibly have with a static variable on program exit.  Which operating system doesn't reclaim ALL of the resources used by a process when the process terminates?

Comment: @JUST, it will produce false positives on valgrind and friends even if it's reclaimed by the OS eventually.

Comment: @bdonlan: Really? Bear in mind that the static variable *lives to the end of the application anyway*, so it never actually leaks, no matter what way you look at it.

Comment: Not all memory can be reclaimed by all OSs. The global COM heap is an excellent example.

Comment: @Peter Alexander: I can see how valgrind would get confused if you have a static pointer to dynamically-created objects.  This sounds, however, more like a limitation of valgrind than it sounds like a problem with letting the OS contend with things.  @DeadMG: So if you're using the global COM heap you've got a bit more work to do than if you're using plain old C++ objects.  In most C++ programs, however, under all but the pathological cases of platform limitations, it's perfectly OK to leave a program without manually releasing static resources.

Answer (score 2):

**for global static variables:**

```
CFoo* pFoo= NULL;

void DoneFoo()
{
    delete pFoo;
}

void Init()
{
    pFoo= new CFoo();
    atexit(DoneFoo);
}
```

or:

```
class CFoo
{
     ......
};

#define NewFoo(F_name)                                                             \
    CFoo* F_name##Init();                                                          \
    void  F_name##Done();                                                          \
    CFoo* F_name= F_name##Init();                                                  \
    CFoo* F_name##Init()  { CFoo* F= new CFoo(); atexit(F_name##Done); return F; } \
    void  F_name##Done()  { delete F_name; }    

NewFoo(F1);
```

**for member static variables:**

```
class CFoo
{
    static int* pKuku;
    static void DoneKuku() { delete pKuku;                     }
    static int* InitKuku() { atexit(DoneKuku); return new int; }
public:
};

int* CFoo::pKuku= CFoo::InitKuku();
```

I don't think it is a good idea to let the OS free memory automatically, because you'll have memory leaks. When you have 'legitimate' memory leaks - it will be harder to notice 'illegitimate' ones, so you should strive to having no memory leaks at all.

Comment: +1: I also think that letting the OS reclaim memory is not the way to go, for once it clutters the output of memory leak detection tools :/

Answer (score 1):

Since it's static, there will only ever be one instance. Unless this GLUtesselator is really huge, I doubt you will ever need to free it yourself.

like you said, "Oh, whatever, the application is terminated. The OS will free the memory..."